# vuetify v-switch change inactive color

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I wanted to create a v-switch element with vuetify but also wanted to have custom color for both state on and off and can't figure out how to achieve it.
Visually what i hope getting looks like.

[image]

I tried the following code pen but the only change was made around the button halo and not the toggle switch content color and background slider.

https://codepen.io/DutchmanSA/pen/rgdzBq

for now my code is here

https://codepen.io/fprm-the-lessful/pen/WNzNLed

html

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card flat>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-container fluid>
          <v-row>
            <div class="d-flex">
              <p 
                 class="mr-1 my-auto"
                 :class="!myswitch?'purple--text text--darken-2 font-weight-bold':'grey--text'"
                 > My off Value </p>
              <v-switch
                v-model="myswitch"
                value="error"
                color="blue darken-2"
                hide-details
                class="mt-n1 custom-red"
              ></v-switch>
              <p 
                 class="mx-auto my-auto"
                 :class="myswitch?'blue--text text--darken-2 font-weight-bold':'grey--text'"
              >
                My on Value
              </p>
            </div>
             
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.custom-red .v-input--selection-controls__input div {
  color: #6A1B9A;
}
```

i m using Vue 2.6 and vuetify 2.4
appreciate a little help
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this to your css:

```
.v-input--switch:not(.v-input--switch--flat):not(.v-input--switch--inset) .v-input--switch__thumb {
  color: purple
}

.theme--light.v-input--switch .v-input--switch__track {
  color: purple
}
```

Comment: Perfect worked like a charm. did you now where i can find the list of css properties of vuetify element, in the doc i only get saas variables but could find more infos.

Comment: @floprm I do not think there is any official documentation but you can find all the information about styling for every component on their [github](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/tree/master/packages/vuetify/src/components)

Comment: Thanks @TymoteuszLao not sure i would find my way out in the sass but it would for sure be helpfull in the future

Comment: Little update in some cases you need to add ::v-deep in front of your scoped css declaration like.  ::v-deep .custom-deactivate.v-input--selection-controls__input div {
  color: #0dac35;
}
::v-deep .custom-deactivate.v-input--switch:not(.v-input--switch--flat):not(.v-input--switch--inset) .v-input--switch__thumb {
  color: #0dac35
}

::v-deep .custom-deactivate.theme--light.v-input--switch .v-input--switch__track {
  color: #0dac35
}

Answer (score 0):

I did lot of research to find out any default `property`/`attribute` to change the color of `<v-switch>` in off state but did not find anything, I also tried to put a watcher on model value and was successfully able to find the `on`/`off` state as per the value change but color change not happening.

Now as per the 2nd codepen demo link you shared in the post, Looks like you can achieve the requirement by just downgrading the vuetify version from `2.*` to `1.*`. Here is the live demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      myswitch: false
    };
  }
})
```

```css
.custom-purple .v-input--selection-controls__input div {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card flat>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-container fluid>
          <v-row>
            <div class="d-flex">
              <p class="mr-1 my-auto"
                 :class="!myswitch ? 'purple--text text--darken-2 font-weight-bold' : 'grey--text'"> My off Value </p>
              <v-switch
                        v-model="myswitch"
                        color="primary"
                        class="mt-n1 custom-purple"
                        ></v-switch>
              <p class="mx-auto my-auto"
                 :class="myswitch?'blue--text text--darken-2 font-weight-bold':'grey--text'">
                My on Value
              </p>
            </div>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but i have a huge project and a lot of other element in vuetify 2 the side effect of downgrading would cost me to much

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the above solutions didn't work for me, the css classes were not applied. Do the following:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function() {
    return {
      busyOk: false
    };
  }
})
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

label {
   text-indent: 1em;
}
label:before {
   background-color: lightgray;
   content: "";
   width: 2em;
   height: 1em;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
}

.track {
   background-color: gray;
   position: absolute;
   width: 1em;
   height: 1em;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
   opacity: 0;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .track {
   left: 1em;
   background-color: #E63946;
}

.busy-text{
   colour: #E63946;
   caret-color: #E63946;
   font-weight: bold;
}

.available-text{
   colour: #07BEB8;
   caret-color: #07BEB8;
   font-weight: bold;
}

label {
   user-select: none;
   cursor: pointer;
   line-height: 1em;
   transform: scale(1.8);
}
label:before {
   background-color: rgba(233, 227, 227, 0.904);
   border: solid 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
   border-radius: 1em;
}

.track {
   background-color: #07BEB8;
   transition: left 100ms;
   border-radius: 50%;
   box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-card flat>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-container fluid>
          <v-row>
            <div class="d-flex">

              <v-card-text class="mt-5">
                <div class="d-flex justify-center">  
                   <div :class="!busyOk?'available-text':'grey--text'" class="title">Text One</div>
                   <label class="mx-6 my-auto" for="check" id="app">
                    <input id="check" type="checkbox" v-model="busyOk"/>
                    <div class="track"></div>
                   </label>
                    <div :class="busyOk?'busy-text':'grey--text'" class="title">Text Two</div>
                </div>
              </v-card-text>

            </div>
          </v-row>
        </v-container>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).